When I SIgn Out, Bluetooth Services Appear to Stop Working
Good day,
I have recently installed Ubuntu 24 LTS on an HP 15-dy1731ms Laptop with integrated Bluetooth. Directly before the reformat, Bluetooth was working flawlessly. To elaborate upon the title, when I sign out, close the laptop lid, or lock the device bluetooth  appears to stop working. The indicator goes away and I cannot re-enable from settings. When I restart the laptop and log in, bluetooth works flawlessly.
Bluetooth Status
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
 Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-09-05 09:33:16 EDT; 2h 15min ago
   Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)   Main PID: 931 (bluetoothd)
 Status: "Running"
  Tasks: 1 (limit: 9074)
 Memory: 3.7M (peak: 4.0M)
    CPU: 100ms
 CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
         └─931 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd 
Sep 05 09:53:15 david-HP-Laptop-15-dy1xxx bluetoothd[931]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx
Sep 05 09:53:15 david-HP-Laptop-15-dy1xxx bluetoothd[931]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Sep 05 09:53:15 david-HP-Laptop-15-dy1xxx bluetoothd[931]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Sep 05 09:53:15 david-HP-Laptop-15-dy1xxx bluetoothd[931]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
Sep 05 09:53:15 david-HP-Laptop-15-dy1xxx bluetoothd[931]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_4>
Sep 05 09:53:15 david-HP-Laptop-15-dy1xxx bluetoothd[931]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
Sep 05 09:53:15 david-HP-Laptop-15-dy1xxx bluetoothd[931]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_5>
Sep 05 09:53:15 david-HP-Laptop-15-dy1xxx bluetoothd[931]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
Sep 05 09:53:15 david-HP-Laptop-15-dy1xxx bluetoothd[931]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_5>

lsmod | grep -i blu
bluetooth            1028096  15 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth

Curiously, rfkill list all
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no


I fixed my own problem by following the guide here
